# Would it be in violation of student visa to spend a substantial amount of time and make profits from stocks?

Tags: germany, immigration, work-permit

Follow up to [this question](/questions/92177). As far as I know, one cannot do freelance work while on a student visa. So, for example, I cannot do something like hair cutting or drawing on commission, while in country.

> Freelance visa
> The student visa does not allow you to freelance. It is possible to apply for an exception at the immigration authority (Ausländerbehörde), see section 21 (6) Residence Act. If your specific freelancing activity does not allow you to easily keep track on the number of hours you freelance then the exception will likely not be granted.
>
> [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/germany/wiki/studying/financing/#wiki_freelance_visa)

Now, I have this friend of mine, and he claims to say that he makes an incredible amount of money, thousands of euros from stocks. And, to my understanding, he spends a lot of time on it, perhaps as much as one would do, if they were employed in a job.

Does this make it illegal in virtue of the same idea in the quoted paragraph? If not, why?

Comment: Is your friend someone you've physically met or just someone you know via chat/email/social media? I only ask because there are innumerable online scams that start with "I'm making tons of money in the [stock market/currency trading/crypto trading]. You should try it too!"

Comment: Immigration is totally outside my wheelhouse, but I assume you would be entitled to do all the same research and make all the exact same trades if you were back home. I don't see why this would be problematic.

Comment: I agree with @bdb484. Managing _your own_ capital is not work, § 2 ⑵ AufenthG.

Comment: Don't touch this. Even if this friend is someone you know. Passive investment beats inflation and makes you 5% (but not right now). Active stock trading is a job for the 1% of Wall Street class traders, gambling for the rest, and a scam for the fools.